# PHP MYSQL PDO INSERT with join or how?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I'm trying to create a messaging system for my site the tables in the Mysql DB looks like this:

```
PM_HEAD

PM_HEAD_ID (Primary key,AI,INT)
PM_SUBJECT (VARCHAR)
PM_TO (VARCHAR)
PM_FROM (VARCHAR)
```

.

```
PM_ROWS

PM_HEAD_ID (INT, FK)
PM_ROWS_ID (INT,Primary key,AI)
PM_MESSAGE (TEXT)
PM_DATE (DATETIME)
PM_FROM (VARCHAR)
PM_TO (VARCHAR)
```

How do i create my PDO query for inserting on a new message?
i've tried a couple of joins, but after reading up on it abit it seems that mysql dont support insert with join?

I need some advice on how i should proceed when a user messages another for the first time, a reply wont be such a hazzle...

Comment: Why don't you just make this one table? I don't see the need for two tables.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois That's bad normalization. `PM_HEAD` is the conversation, and `PM_ROWS` is each message in the conversation.

Comment: I don't see any need for a join. There's no information being copied from one table to the other.

Comment: When the user messages someone for the first time you insert into `PM_HEAD`, get the ID that was assigned with `$pdo->lastInsertId()`, then use that in the `PM_HEAD_ID` when you insert into `PM_ROWS`.

Comment: When a user continues a conversation, you get the `PM_HEAD_ID` from the client, and use that when inserting another row into `PM_ROWS`.

Comment: @Barmar yes, that seems like the solution im going for, however in the fist message there is still a PM_MESSAGE that needs to go into PM_ROWS, there is the problem so i need like 2 queries in the same pdo?

Comment: For the first message you have to do two inserts. First insert into PM_HEAD, then insert into PM_ROWS.

Comment: you can't do two queries in the same call. Do them as two separate PDO calls.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks alot it solved my problem, a gold star to you!

Comment: @barmar answer the question and ill mark it as solved :)

Comment: It's a bad question, not worth answering.